# asynchronous load of multiple URLs

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

I want to load multiple images in table view.and it should be loaded asynchronously from urls.I tried many times but I am not getting...can anyone help me into this?
I am getting problem in loading from cellforrowindex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question may be duplicated but :

[Check This](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/)

[Apple LazyLoading](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

[And this one](http://londonwebdev.com/2011/01/14/lazy-loading-multiple-images-on-background-threads-on-the-iphone/)

Comment: i am don't see your code so try third one . it has source code of the app .

Comment: ya thanks!I got from that way.. but i want to use nsurlconnection ..which is mentiond in first link..and not getting .can u help me

Comment: can u tell me in first link u mention..where to put multiple urls ??